# FileNotFoundException (Logback) while starting app

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, intellij-idea, logback

When running `SpringBoot 2.0.3` app on tomcat `8.5.0` i get following error:

> ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - 
>   openFile(C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat
>   9.0\temp/spring.log,true) call failed.  java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\temp\spring.log
>   (Access is denied)

`logback-spring.xml` from this module is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <springProperty scope="context" name="springAppName" source="spring.application.name"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <include resource="logback-json.xml"/>
    <property name="LOG_PATTERN"
              value="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}|${springAppName}|[%X{X-B3-TraceId:-},%X{X-B3-SpanId:-},%X{X-Span-Export:-}]|%thread|%.-1level|%logger{10}|%msg%n"/>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${catalina.base}/logs/${springAppName}.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${catalina.base}/logs/${springAppName}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>200MB</maxFileSize>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="pl.X" level="debug"/>

    <logger name="jdbc.sqltiming" level="info"/>

    <appender name="ASYNC_REQUEST_RESPONSE_JSON_LOG" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="REQUEST_RESPONSE_JSON_LOG"/>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ASYNC_ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="ROLLING"/>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ASYNC_SERVER_JSON_LOG" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="SERVER_JSON_LOG"/>
    </appender>
    <logger name="somePakaes.trace.XLoggingFilter" additivity="false" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_REQUEST_RESPONSE_JSON_LOG"/>
    </logger>
    <root level="WARN">
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_ROLLING"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_SERVER_JSON_LOG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
```

And here is `logback-json.xml` that above files refers to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<included>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="springAppName" source="spring.application.name"/>

    <appender name="SERVER_JSON_LOG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${catalina.base}/logs/${springAppName}.json</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${catalina.base}/logs/${springAppName}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.json.zip</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>200MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>2</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
            <providers>
                <pattern>
                    <pattern>
                        {
                        "date":"%date",
                        "severity": "%level",
                        "service": "${springAppName}",
                        "trace": "%X{X-B3-TraceId:-}",
                        "span": "%X{X-B3-SpanId:-}",
                        "parent": "%X{X-B3-ParentSpanId:-}",
                        "exportable": "%X{X-Span-Export:-}",
                        "pid": "${PID:-}",
                        "thread": "%thread",
                        "class": "%logger{26}",
                        "message": "%message",
                        "ex": "%ex"
                        }
                    </pattern>
                </pattern>
            </providers>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter" level="error"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceHandlerInterceptor" level="error"/>


    <appender name="REQUEST_RESPONSE_JSON_LOG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${catalina.base}/logs/${springAppName}_request_response.json</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${catalina.base}/logs/${springAppName}_request_response-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.json.zip</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>200MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>2</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
            <providers>
                <pattern>
                    <pattern>
                        {
                        "date":"%date",
                        "service": "${springAppName}",
                        "severity": "%level",
                        "trace": "%X{X-B3-TraceId:-}",
                        "span": "%X{X-B3-SpanId:-}",
                        "parent": "%X{X-B3-ParentSpanId:-}",
                        "pid": "${PID:-}",
                        "thread": "%thread",
                        "message": "%message"
                        }
                    </pattern>
                </pattern>
            </providers>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
</included>
```

But the problem disappears when running InteliJ as an `admin`.

Comment: **(Access is denied)** Program Files is a protected directory and cannot be accessed without administrator permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Two reasons you might facing in this condition:

1. See if you have permission to read *spring.log* file or not this is
   the most obvious reason of `java.io.FileNotFoundException`: (Access is
   denied) exception and I didn't had sufficient permission so I
   immediately provided **read, write and execute** permission to the log
   file and tried again.
2. See if some other process is using that file This could be another
   possible reason of `java.io.FileNotFoundException`: (Access is
   denied).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have the save error message like you,
`....call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException`

The point is the user who runs the application does not have permission to write log file, look at your `.service` file to find who runs the application.
However, if you want to pass this problem **easily** just change permission of "logs" folder to 777

```
 <file>${catalina.base}/logs/${springAppName}.log</file>
```

by using this linux command.

> chmod 777 logs

Doing this solve my problem.